# What's the Debian way to retain a kernel config change through updates?

Tags: debian, kernel, package-management

I have an embedded system running Debian. It is supposed to auto-update in order to pull in security fixes. But Debian's default kernel lacks a hardware driver that this system needs, so it will need to run a self-compiled kernel.

Is there a way to request that, whenever a new kernel-source package comes out, the system should "make oldconfig" with the addition of that one config change we need, and install and use the resulting kernel binary?

Alternatively, if that's impossible for Debian, is there a distribution with similar long-term-stable qualities (so... not exactly Gentoo) that allows doing this?

Comment: I used DKMS to autocompile microchip serial drivers before they were mainline, perhaps that will work for you?

Comment: it invariably involves months of heated and pointless debate whatever it is

Comment: If the driver can be compiled as a module, you could file a bug in Debian and ask for it to be added to the default kernel.